# Finding residue to show reverse Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-integration

Show from direct integration that the Fourier transform of the function

$ f(t) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{-1 < t < 0} \\
-1, & \text{0 < t < 1} \\
0, & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$

is $f(k)= \frac{2i(1-cos(k))}{k}$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^0 (1)e^{-ikt} & = [\frac{-ie^{-ikt}}{k}]_1^0 dt- \\
& = \frac{-ie^{-ik(0)}}{k} + \frac{ie^{-ik(-1)}}{k} \\
& = \frac{-i}{k} + \frac{ie^{ik}}{k}\\
\end{align}

Second part

\begin{align}
\int_0^1 (-1)e^{-ikt} & = [\frac{ie^{-ikt}}{k}]_0^1 \\
& = \frac{ie^{-ik(1)}}{k} - \frac{ie^{-ik(0)}}{k} \\
& = \frac{ie^{-ik}}{k} - \frac{i}{k} \\
\end{align}

adding them together

\begin{align}
\frac{-i}{k} + \frac{ie^{ik}}{k} + \frac{-ie^{ik}}{k} - \frac{i}{k} & = \frac{-2i}{k} + \frac{ie^{ik}+ie^{-ik}}{k} \\ 
& = \frac{-2i + ie^{ik} +ie^{-ik}}{k} \\ 
& = \frac{-2i+2i(\frac{e^{ik}+e^{-ik}}{2})}{k} \\
& = \frac{-2i+2i({cos(k)})}{k} \\
& = \frac{2i(-1+cos(k))}{k} 
\end{align}

I can't see where I have made an error here.

The second part asks to use complex integration to find the inverse Fourier transform, show that
\begin{align}
f(k)= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{2i(1-cos(k))}{k}e^{ikt}
\end{align}

I am struggling finding my residue now that I can't use my p-over-q, so far I have:

\begin{align}
\frac{i}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{(1-cos(k))}{k}e^{ikt}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
p(k) & = e^{ikt}-e^{ikt}cosk \\
q(k) & = k \\
q'(k) & = 1
\end{align}

I run into trouble because
\begin{align}
p(0) & = e^0-e^0cos(0) \\ 
& = 1 - 1(1)\\
& = 0
\end{align}

So I can't use the p-over-q rule but I don't know how to find my residue to show f(t)=1 at -1<t<0 (I haven't tried to use Jordan's Lemma yet because I can't find the residue)